# Is SO_REUSEADDR deprecated since SO_REUSEPORT is available under Linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, kernel

As described in [How do SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/how-do-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-differ), since Linux kernel 3.9, `SO_REUSEPORT` is available.

To my understanding, `SO_REUSEPORT` can do all things that `SO_REUSEADDR` can do, but more handy.

So, can we safely say:

**`SO_REUSEADDR` has been depecated by `SO_REUSEPORT` under Linux?**

Comment: "can we safely say: SO_REUSEADDR has been depecated by SO_REUSEPORT under Linux?" - No, because it is **not marked** as deprecated. See e.g. [man socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html). (The fact that one option is superseded by another one doesn't *automatically* deprecate the first option. Deprecation is an **official procedure**.)

Comment: Can we safely ignore `SO_REUSEADDR` because  we already have `SO_REUSEADDR`?

Comment: Neither from `man socket` nor from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14388707/3440745) to the question you refer I see no evidence that `SO_REUSEPORT` can replace `SO_REUSEADDR` in all aspects on Linux.

Comment: I cannot imagine any scenario in which `SO_REUSEPORT` doesn't work but `SO_REUSEADDR` works.